# sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, httpclient

I am writing a Python HTTP client.
When I have the code below I get an error message from the terminal "list index out of range".

```
from socket import *
import sys

server_host = sys.argv[1]
server_port = sys.argv[2]
filename = sys.argv[3]

host_port = "%s:%s" %(server_host, server_port)
try:
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    clientSocket.connect((server_host,int(server_port)))
    header = {
    "first_header" : "GET /%s HTTP/1.1" %(filename),
    "Host": host_port,
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US",
    }
    httpHeader = "\r\n".join("%s:%s" %(item,header[item]) for item in     header)
    print httpHeader
    clientSocket.send("%s\r\n\r\n" %(httpHeader))

except IOError:

    sys.exit(1)
final = ""
responseMessage = clientSocket.recv(1024)
while responseMessage:
    final += responseMessage
    responseMssage = clientSocket.recv(1024)

clientSocket.close()
print "final:",final
```

I run the program from the command line by typing

```
python ./client.py http://127.0.0.1 7000 HelloWorld.html
```

Could anybody show me what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with this. Try executing it like: ./client.py 127.0.0.1 7000 HelloWorld.html

Comment: it starts with argv[0]

Comment: You can debug your code, no? Simply print out `sys.argv` and see what is happening

Comment: @haifzhan I think that is the name of the script.

Comment: Can you print the exact error with line no. info

Comment: I copied those first 5 lines of code, and I can't reproduce.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing those command line arguments? try `print len(sys.argv)` before the problem line. Is it the number you expect (i.e. 4)?

Comment: @PaulRooney Yeah. I want to get 4, but the result I got was 1.

Comment: It's usual to put a check at the start of the file to ensure that the expected number of arguments are present and print an error message and exit early if they are not. Are you sure thats how you are invoking your script?

Comment: Doing manual checks for arguments is a bit out of date, this should be done using ```argparse``` it is much easier and saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `argparse` instead of handling sys.argv manually? For example:

```
import argparse as ap

def argParse():
    parser=ap.ArgumentParser(description='Script to do something')
    parser.add_argument("host", help="web address")
    parser.add_argument("port", help="port to connect on")
    parser.add_argument("filename",help="page to use")
    return parser.parse_args()
```

Then in the main function call:

```
args=argParse()
```

Then you can use `args.host`, `args.port` and `args.filename` in your code and argparse will handle missing arguments and they types etc. You can use optional arguments by adding `--` in front of their definitions in the `add_argument()` call.

Your code using argparse:

```
from socket import *
import argparse as ap

def argParse():
    parser=ap.ArgumentParser(description='Script to do something')
    parser.add_argument("host", help="web address")
    parser.add_argument("port", type=int, help="port to connect on")
    parser.add_argument("filename",help="page to use")
    return parser.parse_args()

args=argParse()

host_port = "%s:%d" % (args.host, args.port)
try:
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    clientSocket.connect((args.host,args.port))
    header = {
    "first_header" : "GET /%s HTTP/1.1" % (args.filename),
    "Host": str(args.port),
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US",
    }
    httpHeader = "\r\n".join("%s:%s" %(item,header[item]) for item in     header)
    print httpHeader
    clientSocket.send("%s\r\n\r\n" %(httpHeader))

except IOError:

    sys.exit(1)
final = ""
responseMessage = clientSocket.recv(1024)
while responseMessage:
    final += responseMessage
    responseMssage = clientSocket.recv(1024)

clientSocket.close()
print "final:",final
```